# Initializing a Fragment without FragmentTransactions or .commit? Mistaken?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, wifi-direct

I am currently figuring out WIFIDirect, mainly by following Google's demo, listed below

(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect)

I have been seriously confused by the way the demo is launching a detail fragment from a listFragment, where an interface call from the parent host activity (showDetails(device)), shown below

```
@Override
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
fragment.showDetails(device);
}
```

We are then bouncedto the detailFragment's own showDetails(device)) method:

```
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
this.device = device;
this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
view.setText(device.toString());
}
```

I did a search through the code, there was no .commit() or FragmentTransaction anywhere. I suspect it's the .getView.SET_VISIBILITY call, but without a .commit, nothing should happen correct?. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a transaction if the Fragment is directly in the xml.  You only need a transaction when you're swapping an on screen element for a fragment.

Comment: Ah yes, I just found it. I've never used fragments in this way. Thank you!